# Functional JS Set all Properties on an Object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an object `myObj` like:

```
{
  0: true,
  1: false,
  2: false
}
```

To set each value to `true`, I could use a loop:

```
for (i in myObj) {
  myObj[i] = true
}
```

But is there a functional way to do this in javascript? Something like:

```
myOjb.fill(true)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement such a function without using a `for` loop? Or whether such a method exists natively? It does not. In many of these cases, `.reduce` is your friend.

Comment: I'd say `for (k in myObj) myObj[k] = true;` is probably the easiest, fastest and most concise way to do that, there is no magic function !

Comment: I think I'm asking what the best functional way to do this is.

Comment: That looks like more of a custom requirement. Which language do you know that natively comes with a "fill" type of method?

Comment: @TravisJ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: @jcuenod: And what is a measure of "best"? Performance? Conciseness? Readability?

Comment: @FelixKling how would you do it?

Comment: I would use a `for` loop :P

Comment: You can always create your own reusable functions, if that's what you actually want: `function fill(obj, v) { for (...) { .... }; return obj; }`.

Comment: Ja, this is really more me trying to figure out functional programming a bit more. I have used a for loop but I thought it would be cool to do it functionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (if available in your environment). It enumerates keys on the current object, skipping prototype properties and the like.

You would simply do:

```
function fill(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    obj[key] = true;
  });
}
```

If you want to get really functional with it, you can use reduce and avoid side-effects:

```
function fill(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (p, key) {
    p[key] = true;
    return p;
  }, {});
}
```

If you want to keep the same prototype as the original object, assuming you're working with simple types that have no-arg constructors (object and array count), you can use `obj.constructor` like:

```js
function fill(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, key) {
    p[key] = true;
    return p;
  }, new obj.constructor);
}

var filledObject = fill({
  bar: false,
  baz: 3,
  boo: 'test'
});
var filledArray = fill([1, 2, 3, 4, false, 'test']);

document.getElementById('obj').textContent = JSON.stringify(filledObject);
document.getElementById('arr').textContent = JSON.stringify(filledArray);

var evilSparseArray = [1, 2, 3];
evilSparseArray[19] = 4;
document.getElementById('spa').textContent = JSON.stringify(fill(evilSparseArray));
```

```html
<pre id="obj"></pre>
<pre id="arr"></pre>
<pre id="spa"></pre>
```

Note that this will *not* work correctly with sparse arrays, since the other keys are defined but don't have meaningful data.

Comment: `reduce` on the keys is what I hadn't thought of - that's pretty cool.

Comment: I think `reduce` is the most reasonable functional way of doing this. It's simple and should be acceptably quick. The behavior of `Object.keys` is very convenient here, since it works on arrays as well.

Comment: I'd rather use `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` instead of `new this.constructor` (it doesn't have any side effects if we do FP, does it?)

Comment: @Bergi swapping the `new` for `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))` doesn't seem to work in my browser: it always returns an object.

Comment: What's wrong with objects? Do you mean the array case?

Comment: Yep. `Object.create` always returns an object, even if `obj`'s prototype was `Array`. Using `new obj.constructor` is a little bit less idiomatic and could cause errors, but creates a new array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it if you will have your index as values

```
   function convertObjectToValue (myObject, val) { 
     myObject.length = Object.keys(myObject).length;
     return Array.prototype.slice.apply(myObject).map(function () {
         return val;
     }).reduce(function(obj, index, value) {
         obj[index] = value;
     },{});
   }
```

Comment: `[].slice` won't work on an object, `map(function (it) { return it; })` is a no-op (and can be optimized out), and this will convert everything into an object (even if it started as an array, a flaw FelixKling noted on my answer as well).

Comment: @ssube i pointed out this won't work unless you have your index as numbers but yes your answer this is just a different verity which will work if you have 0-> n index numbers.